# Entity Framework 6 - get relationship count without loading entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I know this question has been asked a few times on SO, but I can't find an answer which relates to my problem. They all link to this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#queryCount, which works perfectly fine, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

So, basically, I would like to get the count of the relationship, without loading the actual entities, just do a COUNT sql.

Unlike the example from MSDN, I'm looking for a way to do it without explicitly instancing a new DbContext. I would like to put the count methods inside the entity class. I believe context shouldn't be instanced from entity classes.

Also, since the entity is already loaded, it already exists in one context. Could the count queries be executed in that same context? Basically the same as lazy loading of relationship entities work. They are loaded in the same context as the main object, although the object doesn't know its context and you don't have to create it explicitly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would prefer to maintain a TotalXXX property in the main object, like Category.TotalProducts, which is also mapped to a table column. So what u need to do is to update the TotalXXX correctly. And the count query is super cheap in this way.

Comment: I would also like to maintain it in the main object as a property, but without the extra calculated column